# How to move SVG's position in D3?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I created a svg using D3. However, it only shows up on the upper left conner of the screen, or been appended to another svg. Are there anyway I can move it using JavaScript?
For example:

```
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200);
```

Comment: Without css nor js, your svg will always be at the top left of its container. Some tricks for new SO users : use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ncyg5hcd/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using d3js + Jquery :

```
// svg design
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200);

// svg repositioning
$("svg").css({top: 200, left: 200, position:'absolute'});
```

Or

```
// svg align center
d3.select("#chart").attr("align","center"); //  thanks & +1 to chaitanya89
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ncyg5hcd/20/)

Comment: This answer perfectly solved my problem. Thank you for your tips!

Comment: @Photunix: please +1 other answers as well as they spent time trying to solve your question. Thanks also for the validation, happy it works!

Answer (score 9):

Instead of appending SVG to the body, append it to a html element like `<div>` and add style to it.

Javascript:

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
.attr("width", 200)
.attr("height", 200);
```

HTML:
add this to your body tag.

```
<div id="chart" align="center"></div>
```

If you want to align svg using javascript, remove `align` attribute in the above `<div>` tag and add the following in your javascript.

```
document.getElementById("chart").align = "center";
```

Alternatively, You could also do it using D3.

```
d3.select("#chart")
.attr("align","center");
```

Comment: Use JS to position the #chart, it will fit better the question.

Comment: I'am pretty sure the asker will forget to +1 us =__=

Comment: Thank you for your help. But Hugolpz has a more instutive answer for me. Hope you do not mind. I will vote you up once I get 15 reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Before you need append any SVG object to apply the transition on canvas.

The tutorial step-by-step below show you, in practice, each property of method Transition from D3js.

http://blog.visual.ly/creating-animations-and-transitions-with-d3-js/

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Use negative value in margin.

margin = { top: 20, right: -600, bottom: 20, left: 640 }

The content is added on the left by default. To shift to right, use negative margins.
following line will take it to the second right half of the screen.