# d3.js map stubbornly sticking to left of page. how to center?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I've tried to add `align="center"` to the html elements in which the map lives, but this was totally ineffectual.

I've looked at [related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232333/how-to-move-svgs-position-in-d3) here on stackoverflow that suggest appending values to the svg but that likewise was not working.

Below is the code I'm using.

How can I ensure that it will be centered on the page and not stuck to the left?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>
    <title>European Data Science Academy (EDSA) 2015</title>

    <script src='javascripts/d3.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='javascripts/crossfilter.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='javascripts/dc.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='javascripts/bootstrap.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>

    <link href='stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style type="text/css">
    <link href='stylesheets/dc.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dc.css"/>  

    .background {
      fill: none;
      pointer-events: all;

      display: block;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .feature {
      fill: #ccc;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .feature.active {
      fill: orange;
    }

    .mesh {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-linecap: round;
      stroke-linejoin: round;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- This is the Tittle of the First Container  -->
    <div class='navbar navbar-fixed-top'>
        <div class='navbar-inner'>
            <div class='container'>
                <a class="brand">European Data Science Academy (EDSA)</a>
                <img src="img/edsalogo2.png" alt="European Data Science Academy" width="142" height="142" align="right">
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>



<!-- This is the main frame   -->
<div class='container' id='main-container'>
        <div class='content'>
            <div class='container' style='font: 11px sans-serif;'>
                <h3>Visualisation of Numbers of Data Science Jobs</h3>
                <h4> Demo</h4>

                <!-- This is the frame that contains the Map, Employer, Data Table-->
                <div class='row-fluid'>
                    <div class='remaining-graphs span8'>

                    <!-- This is the frame that contains the Map-->
                        <div class='row-fluid'>
                            <div id="us-chart" align="center">
                            <!--<div class='bubble-graph span12' id='dc-bubble-graph'> -->
                                <h4>Distribution of Jobs by Country</h4>
                                <a class="reset" href="javascript:usChart.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();" style="display: none;">Reset</a>

                                <!--This is the reset class of the Map -->
                                <span class="reset" style="display: none;"> | Current filter: <span class="filter"></span></span>

                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- /other little graphs go here DataTable -->
                        <div class='row-fluid'>
                            <div class='span12 table-graph'>
                                <h4>Data Table for Filtered Countries</h4>
                                <table class='table table-hover dc-data-table' id='dc-table-graph'>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr class='header'>
                                            <th>Country</th>
                                            <th>Location</th>
                                            <th>Skills</th>
                                            <th>Jobs</th>
                                            <th>Employer</th>
                                          <!--  <th>Link</th> -->
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                <!-- This is the frame that contains the Location-->
                    <div class='remaining-graphs span4'>

                        <div class='row-fluid'>
                            <div class='row-graph span8' id='dc-row-graph' style='color:black;'>
                                <h4>Search by Location</h4>
                                     <!-- Reset  filters selected in the pie-->
                                     <a class="reset" href="javascript:pieChart2.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();" style="display: none;">Reset</a>

                                    <!--This is the reset class -->
                                    <span class="reset" style="display: none;"> | Current filter: <span class="filter"></span></span>

                                     <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class='row-graph span4' id='dc-row-graph2' style='color:black;'>
                                <h4>Search by Skills</h4>
                                     <!-- Reset  filters selected in the pie-->
                                     <a class="reset" href="javascript:pieChart2.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();" style="display: none;">Reset</a>

                                    <!--This is the reset class -->
                                    <span class="reset" style="display: none;"> | Current filter: <span class="filter"></span></span>

                                     <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div> <!-- Ediv class='row-fluid'-->
            </div>  <!-- END div class='container' style='font:-->

        </div>  <!-- END div class='content' -->
    </div> <!--END div class='container' id='main-container' -->


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.19/topojson.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dc.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>





<!-- THIS IS THE MOST IMPORTANT PART -->

<script type="text/javascript">


var width = 590,
    height = 500,
    active = d3.select(null);
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    //.center([3.9, 43.0])
    .precision(.1)
    .scale((1200 + 1) / 2 )
    .translate([660 / 4, 3360 / 4]);
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate([0, 0])
    .scale(1)
    .scaleExtent([1, 8])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("click", stopped, true);
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("click", reset);
var g = svg.append("g");
svg
    .call(zoom) // delete this line to disable free zooming
    .call(zoom.event);




d3.json("eu.json", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  g.selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(data, data.objects.europe).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "feature")
      .on("click", clicked);
  g.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(data, data.objects.europe, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "mesh")
      .attr("d", path);
});






function clicked(d) {
  if (active.node() === this) return reset();
  active.classed("active", false);
  active = d3.select(this).classed("active", true);

  var bounds = path.bounds(d),
      dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
      dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
      x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
      y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
      scale = .9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height),
      translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

  svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.translate(translate).scale(scale).event);
}

function reset() {
  active.classed("active", false);
  active = d3.select(null);

  svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.translate([0, 0]).scale(1).event);
}

function zoomed() {
  g.style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.scale + "px");
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

// If the drag behavior prevents the default click,
// also stop propagation so we don’t click-to-zoom.
function stopped() {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) d3.event.stopPropagation();
}






</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-33628816-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>



</body>
</html>
```